# How to change values for all td:nth-of-type(4)

Tags: javascript, html-table, datatable

I'm trying to change value for the 4th column that mean td:nth-of-type(4), with the new value "R$0". I only need to do that only for those orders that have status cancelled. Last column is td:nth-of-type(9) and also I have a span with class.

Here is a PrtSc with the table https://i.gyazo.com/91a4cc3b38e71ce73a5ebfc809a692d6.png

Last Column td code
`<td><span class="status-cancelled">Cancelled</span></td>`

Comment: Do you have some code with markup for the table ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e1z50bpw/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $rows=$('.table tbody tr');
   $rows.each(function(){
      status=$(this).children().last().text();
      if(status=='Cancelled'){
         $(this).children().eq(3).text('R$0');
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually could do that without jQuery ?

```
rows = document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody tr");
Object.keys(rows).forEach(function (key){
        if (rows[key].lastElementChild.innerText == "Cancelled") {
        rows[key].children[3].innerText = 'R$0';
    }
});
```